# net/rpc server stay registered when running test more than once with the 'count' flag

Tags: go, rpc, go-testing

The program creates a rpc server and a client and expose several methods via the rpc interface.
Several test functions testing one of the methods each.

The first test function register the rpc server:

```golang
    RPCServer := new(RPCServer)
    rpc.Register(RPCServer)
    rpc.HandleHTTP()
```

Using a channel, each function wait for the server to signal that it is running and when the client finish, signal the server to shut down.

In the test function:

```golang
    // start the server
    ch := make(chan bool, 1)
    go RunRPCServer(ch)

    // wait for the server to start
    <-ch

    ...Do Some Work...

    // close the server
    ch <- true
    close(ch)
```

and in the server function:

```golang
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp4", "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Could not open a listener port: ", err.Error())
    }
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        wg.Add(1)
        // Start the server
        rpcServer := http.Server{}
        go func() {
            go rpcServer.Serve(listener)
            // signal that the server is running
            ch <- true
            // wait for the command to close the server
            <-ch
            <-ch
            // shutdown server and exit
            if err := rpcServer.Shutdown(context.Background()); err != nil {
                log.Printf("HTTP server Shutdown: %v\n", err)
            }
            listener.Close()
            wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
```

It all works perfectly fine when running the tests once, or even several times with:

> go test -count 1 ./src/rpcserver/
> go test -count 1 ./src/rpcserver/

However, when running

> go test -count 2 ./src/rpcserver/

An error is returned when the second run starts:

> --- FAIL: TestRPCServer (0.00s)
> panic: http: multiple registrations for /*goRPC* [recovered]
> panic: http: multiple registrations for /*goRPC*

I wonder why

> go test -count 2 ./src/rpcserver/

does not behave exactly as:

> go test -count 1 ./src/rpcserver/
> go test -count 1 ./src/rpcserver/

?

And what can be done in order to de-register the server between consecutive run of the tests?

**Edit:**
Here is a full minimal example that illustrates the issue:

**server.go:**

```golang
package rpcserver

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/rpc"
)

type RPCServer int

// RPC: only methods that comply with the following scheme are exported:
// func (t *T) MethodName(argType T1, replyType *T2) error

// Since RPC-exposed methods must takes an argument.
type EmptyArg struct{}

// Expose several methods via the RPC interface:
func (RpcServer *RPCServer) Method_1(emptyArg EmptyArg, reply *string) error {

    *reply = "This is Method_1"
    return nil
}

func (RpcServer *RPCServer) Method_2(emptyArg EmptyArg, reply *string) error {

    *reply = "This is Method_2"
    return nil
}

func (RpcServer *RPCServer) Method_3(emptyArg EmptyArg, reply *string) error {

    *reply = "This is Method_3"
    return nil
}

// should be called only once per process
func RegisterRPCMethods() {

    // Register the rpc methods
    RpcServer := new(RPCServer)
    rpc.Register(RpcServer)
    rpc.HandleHTTP()
}

func RunRPCServer(ch chan struct{}) {

    // Open a listener port
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp4", "127.0.0.1:38659")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("listen error:", err)
    }

    // Print some data
    log.Println("Server running")
    log.Println("network:", listener.Addr().Network())

    // Start the server
    rpcServer := http.Server{}
    go func() {
        go rpcServer.Serve(listener)
        // signal that the server is running
        ch <- struct{}{}
        // wait for the command to close the server
        <-ch
        // shutdown server and exit
        if err := rpcServer.Shutdown(context.Background()); err != nil {
            log.Printf("HTTP server Shutdown: %v\n", err)
        }
        listener.Close()
        // signal that the server is closed
        ch <- struct{}{}
    }()
}
```

**server_test.go:**

```golang
package rpcserver

import (
    "net/rpc"
    "testing"
)

func TestMethod_1(t *testing.T) {

    // call once.
    // (test functions are executed in-order)
    RegisterRPCMethods()

    // start the server
    ch := make(chan struct{})
    go RunRPCServer(ch)

    // wait for the server to start
    <-ch

    // Dial to the rpc server
    client, err := rpc.DialHTTP("tcp", "127.0.0.1:38659")
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Could not dial %s: %s", "127.0.0.1:38659", err.Error())
    }
    // the called function allready asserting type.
    reply := ""
    err = client.Call("RPCServer.Method_1", EmptyArg{}, &reply)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    // close the server
    ch <- struct{}{}
    // wait for the server to close
    <-ch
    close(ch)
}

func TestMethod_2(t *testing.T) {

    // start the server
    ch := make(chan struct{})
    go RunRPCServer(ch)

    // wait for the server to start
    <-ch

    // Dial to the rpc server
    client, err := rpc.DialHTTP("tcp", "127.0.0.1:38659")
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Could not dial %s: %s", "127.0.0.1:38659", err.Error())
    }
    // the called function allready asserting type.
    reply := ""
    err = client.Call("RPCServer.Method_2", EmptyArg{}, &reply)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    // close the server
    ch <- struct{}{}
    // wait for the server to close
    <-ch
    close(ch)
}

func TestMethod_3(t *testing.T) {

    // start the server
    ch := make(chan struct{})
    go RunRPCServer(ch)

    // wait for the server to start
    <-ch

    // Dial to the rpc server
    client, err := rpc.DialHTTP("tcp", "127.0.0.1:38659")
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Could not dial %s: %s", "127.0.0.1:38659", err.Error())
    }
    // the called function allready asserting type.
    reply := ""
    err = client.Call("RPCServer.Method_3", EmptyArg{}, &reply)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    // close the server
    ch <- struct{}{}
    // wait for the server to close
    <-ch
    close(ch)
}
```

When running:

> go test -v -count 1 ./src/server/...

The output is as expected:

> === RUN   TestMethod_1
> 2022/05/11 10:59:49 Server running
> 2022/05/11 10:59:49 network: tcp
> --- PASS: TestMethod_1 (0.00s)
> === RUN   TestMethod_2
> 2022/05/11 10:59:49 Server running
> 2022/05/11 10:59:49 network: tcp
> --- PASS: TestMethod_2 (0.00s)
> === RUN   TestMethod_3
> 2022/05/11 10:59:49 Server running
> 2022/05/11 10:59:49 network: tcp
> --- PASS: TestMethod_3 (0.00s)
> PASS
> ok      lsfrpc/src/server   0.008s

And when running

> go test -v -count 1 ./src/server/...
> go test -v -count 1 ./src/server/...

Everything working fine (the output above, twice)

However, when running:

> go test -v -count 2 ./src/server/...

There is an error at the beginning of the second run:

> === RUN   TestMethod_1
> 2022/05/11 10:59:52 Server running
> 2022/05/11 10:59:52 network: tcp
> --- PASS: TestMethod_1 (0.00s)
> === RUN   TestMethod_2
> 2022/05/11 10:59:52 Server running
> 2022/05/11 10:59:52 network: tcp
> --- PASS: TestMethod_2 (0.00s)
> === RUN   TestMethod_3
> 2022/05/11 10:59:52 Server running
> 2022/05/11 10:59:52 network: tcp
> --- PASS: TestMethod_3 (0.00s)
> === RUN   TestMethod_1
> --- FAIL: TestMethod_1 (0.00s)
> panic: http: multiple registrations for /*goRPC* [recovered]
> panic: http: multiple registrations for /*goRPC*
>
> goroutine 63 [running]:
> testing.tRunner.func1.2({0x7b9f20, 0xc0002927f0})
> /home/sivsha01/go/src/testing/testing.go:1389 +0x24e
> testing.tRunner.func1()
> /home/sivsha01/go/src/testing/testing.go:1392 +0x39f
> panic({0x7b9f20, 0xc0002927f0})
> /home/sivsha01/go/src/runtime/panic.go:838 +0x207
> net/http.(*ServeMux).Handle(0xb2e160, {0x83449c, 0x8}, {0x8dc3c0?, 0xc000198000})

Same as I described above. This seems as a wrong behavior to me.

Comment: I think we need more info. But maybe you are having problems waitng for the server to shutdown. You send a message in the chan but you dont wait for the server to exit.

Comment: @ryuk Thank you for your reply. unfortunately waiting for the server to shutdown did not help, please see the minimal code example I added, which do wait for the server to shutdown.

Comment: I saw you are using the same chan, but in a wrong way, I suggest using a separate input and output chan for each task (demand shutdown, wait for it). You are sending a message to the chan and reading it instantly.  `ch <- struct{}{}; <-ch`

Comment: @ryuk Thank you for the observation, I have checked it out and apparently the code I have posted is correct.
Your observation would have been true if the channel was buffered, but it is not possible to self-read an un-buffered channel.
This can also be understood from the spec:

Comment: continue: the spec: [link](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Channel_types) which is admittedly a bit vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reduced version to reproduce the issue:

```golang
package rpcserver

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func TestRegister(t *testing.T) {
    t.Logf("pid: %d", os.Getpid())

    register()
}

func register() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {})
}
```

When you run the test with: `go test -count 2 -v`, you will find that the 2 tests running in the same process. As what is stated in your comment: `RegisterRPCMethods()` **should be called only once per process**.

You can use `sync.Once` to make sure it's just called once:

```golang
package rpcserver

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "testing"
)

func TestRegister(t *testing.T) {
    t.Logf("pid: %d", os.Getpid())

    register()
}

var registerOnce sync.Once

func register() {
    registerOnce.Do(func() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {})
    })
}
```

What's more, your tests won't depend on the execution order of the tests any longer. And all the tests can be run alone.

Comment: Thank you, sync.Once:Do indeed solved this.